# Error while trying to train RandomForest in R

Tags: r, random-forest, rstudio

I have this data:

[image: Dataframe]

> diff is the results of image difference from bitemporal imagery, and 2, 4, 6, and 8 is the bands of PlanetScope imagery.

When I trying to train this data using RandomForest, especially using tuneRF function like this,

```
> rf.tuned <- tuneRF(train[, 1:6], factor(train[, 7]),
                    mtryStart = 15,
                    ntreeTry = 500,
                    stepFactor = 2,
                    improve = 1e-5,
                    trace = TRUE,
                    doBest = FALSE)
```

it has en error output like this:

```
mtry = 15  OOB error = 0% 
Searching left ...
mtry = 8    OOB error = 0% 
NaN 1e-05 
Error in if (Improve > improve) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In randomForest.default(x, y, mtry = mtryStart, ntree = ntreeTry,  :
  invalid mtry: reset to within valid range
2: In randomForest.default(x, y, mtry = mtryCur, ntree = ntreeTry,  :
  invalid mtry: reset to within valid range
```

Before this run, the code was running well. Even if I'm using another data (i.e. Landsat bands + vegetation index).

Comment: That "OOB error = 0%" looks a bit suspicious, like something is degenerate here. With some random data I start with an OOB error of 78%. Does it work on this data with a subset of all the columns? Impossible to help without you trying a few things and updating the question or letting us have your data.

Comment: I tried using other areas with the same imagery and order of raster stack but still got the same problems. I think it's because my population is too big but lack of training samples (even though thousands of samples are selected, but total of pixels is more than 10mil, maybe because of that. I haven't tried your solution yet, maybe after this, I will update it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can replicate something like this if I mistakenly include the class in the predictors.

Sample data:

```
> d = data.frame(diff_ndvi=rnorm(1000), 
    diff_savi=rnorm(1000), 
    diff2=round(runif(1000)*1000),
    diff4=round(runif(1000)*1000),
    diff6=round(runif(1000)*1000), 
    diff8=round(runif(1000)*1000),
    Class=sample(c(1,2,3,4,5),1000,TRUE))
```

looks a bit like your data:

```
> head(d)
   diff_ndvi  diff_savi diff2 diff4 diff6 diff8 Class
1 -0.7959296 -0.6066782   549   415   828   687     2
2  0.4457953  0.2453221   716   467   727   717     1
3  0.2942904  0.2120867   505   537   656   682     2
4 -1.0379374 -0.0376702   587   853   533   266     1
5  0.5692288 -1.5329321   872    45   967   194     2
6  0.6809104 -1.0274901   749   653   663   317     3
```

Then:

```
> rf.tuned <- tuneRF(d[, c(1,2,3,4)], factor(d[, 7]))
mtry = 2  OOB error = 81% 
Searching left ...
mtry = 1    OOB error = 81.8% 
-0.009876543 0.05 
Searching right ...
mtry = 4    OOB error = 81.3% 
-0.003703704 0.05
```

Which looks fine but if I include column 7 in the predictors as well it collapses and gives the same error and warnings and low OOB error as yours:

```
> rf.tuned <- tuneRF(d[, c(1,2,3,4,7)], factor(d[, 7]))
mtry = 2  OOB error = 0% 
Searching left ...
mtry = 1    OOB error = 0.8% 
-Inf 0.05 
Searching right ...
mtry = 4    OOB error = 0% 
NaN 0.05 
Error in if (Improve > improve) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Which will be because its a prefect predictor of itself and somewhere its probably dividing by zero or something.

Check carefully you've not done this.

Answer (score 0):

Well, one error that jumps out is that `randomForest::randomForest.default` is indicating that the mtry parameter is invalid. Given that you have 6 parameters and your start value for mtryStart is 15 this could be a source of error. You should really understand the model parameters before specifying a grid search. The mtry parameter indicates the number of variables to randomly permutate at a given node split and how variable importance is derived. You obviously cannot permute more variables that you have in the data. The mtry default is `ceiling(sqrt(6)) = 3`.

Unlike boosting models, I actually find grid searches on RF models rather erroneous. The default for mtry (classification sqrt(n), regression n/3) is actually fairly stable and does not tend to change variable importance results much. Tree depth is a dangerous parameter to play with and should not be changed unless there is a specific reason. In Breiman (2001), the proofs indicate that one predicate of the model is that the CART's are unconstrained ie., no specified complexity parameter thus, allowing trees to grow to their full depth. In addition the Bootstrapping, this is one thing that prevents overfit. There have been some proposed modification of RF that use conditionally constrained trees but that is a specialty application of the model.

The one relevant parameter to optimize is the number of Bootstrap replicates (ntree). However, one does not need to go to the trouble of a grid search. Just specify a model and then plot it. The resulting plot indicate the OOB error convergence across Bootstrap replicates (globally and per class). If you do not see a stabilization of error, then increase ntree. Just keep in mind that variable interaction stabilizes at a slower rate than error so, one should run more Bootstraps that the error convergence indicates. I would also point out that model selection is an important aspect of fitting a RF model. In a model intended for spatial prediction, without selecting relevant parameters, you run the risk of incorporating noise into your predictions.